# Database Error 1054 : The order cannot be retrieved because Unknown column 'salesorders.internalcomment' in 'field list'

Tags: wpf

I can't Confirm Dispatches and Invoice An Order for customers, and when I try it result into an error I have mentioned, your help please!

Since I haven't understand exactly which table should I add a missing column, have tried to add a missing column in all tables with `sales` description without any success..and Database SQL Failure : The SQL to get the order header was -

> SELECT salesorders.orderno,
>   salesorders.debtorno, debtorsmaster.name, salesorders.branchcode,
>   salesorders.customerref, salesorders.comments,
>   salesorders.internalcomment, salesorders.orddate,
>   salesorders.ordertype, salesorders.shipvia, salesorders.deliverto,
>   salesorders.deladd1, salesorders.deladd2, salesorders.deladd3,
>   salesorders.deladd4, salesorders.deladd5, salesorders.deladd6,
>   salesorders.contactphone, salesorders.contactemail,
>   salesorders.salesperson, salesorders.freightcost,
>   salesorders.deliverydate, debtorsmaster.currcode,
>   salesorders.fromstkloc, locations.taxprovinceid,
>   custbranch.taxgroupid, currencies.rate as currency_rate,
>   currencies.decimalplaces, custbranch.defaultshipvia,
>   custbranch.specialinstructions, pickreq.consignment, pickreq.packages
>   FROM salesorders INNER JOIN debtorsmaster ON salesorders.debtorno =
>   debtorsmaster.debtorno INNER JOIN custbranch ON salesorders.branchcode
>   = custbranch.branchcode AND salesorders.debtorno = custbranch.debtorno INNER JOIN currencies ON debtorsmaster.currcode = currencies.currabrev
>   INNER JOIN locations ON locations.loccode=salesorders.fromstkloc INNER
>   JOIN locationusers ON locationusers.loccode=salesorders.fromstkloc AND
>   locationusers.userid='admin' AND locationusers.canupd=1 LEFT OUTER
>   JOIN pickreq ON pickreq.orderno=salesorders.orderno AND
>   pickreq.closed=0 WHERE salesorders.orderno = '2'

The error was:

> Database Error 1054 : The order cannot be retrieved because Unknown
>   column 'salesorders.internalcomment' in 'field list'

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use code blocks around your code, and include the explicit error message in the body if at all possible.  Also, please verify that your database `salesorders` has `internalcomment` in the column list.

Comment: Thank you very much! the error is gone after adding a column "internalcomment" in database "salesorders"...my problem was misinterpretation of the error message: I thought the name of the missing column is "salesorders.internalcomment". Once again... thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, this was accidentally answered:

Verify the database `salesorders` contains the field/column for `internalcomment` as the error seems to indicate the field is missing entirely.